# [Little Schemer Ch3 pp.34 & 37]: Why (rember a (cdr lat)) as the 2nd argument of cons interpreted as unknown on p.37 example

Tags: debugging, recursion, racket, tail-recursion, the-little-schemer

I run both example on p.34 and p.37 using DrRacket debug mode step by step. And below are the stack windows results when processing `(cdr lat)` the first time of both examples.

p.34, the failed example without `cons`

```
(define rember
  (lambda (a lat)
    (cond
      ((null? lat) '())
      (else (cond
              ((eq? a (car lat)) (cdr lat))
              (else (rember a (cdr lat)))
              )))))

(rember 'c '(a b c d))
```

Stack area in debugger:

> (cdr …) 
>   (rember …)

p.37 with `cons` on last line:

```
(define rember
  (lambda (a lat)
    (cond
      ((null? lat) '())
      (else (cond
              ((eq? a (car lat)) (cdr lat))
              (else (cons (car lat)
                          (rember a (cdr lat)))))))))

(rember 'c '(a b c d))
```

Stack area in debugger:

> (cdr …) 
>   (rember …) 
>   (rember …)

The Stack area with p.37's code indicates that the second call of `rember` has been classified as *unknown* before processing `(cdr lat)`.

The only difference of 2 examples is p.37 added "`cons`". Cons takes 2 arguments, a s-expression and a list.

Without `(cdr lat)`, `rember` itself doesn't return the list. And all the examples containing `(cdr lat)` within the first 40 pages of the book all have the same `(function (cdr variable)` format.

I don't understand why p.37 example `rember` itself being identified as *unknown* and justified for pending reduction while the contained `(cdr lat)` can be processed.

Or why `rember` in the position of 2nd argument of `cons` being interpreted that way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TL;DR:* what you see (and misinterpret) is the *stack of function calls*, and the effects of *tail recursion*.

---

To answer your specific question about the debugger: your interpretation is wrong. What you see there is the *run-time stack* of function calls that got you to *that specific point in execution timeline where you're at right  now*.

It is **not** "unknown", **not** something "to be reduced later". You've already came through it, to your current execution point. What it is, is awaiting the results from the nested invocation, to continue doing its work with *the results*.

If you click on ***Step*** few more times (with the p.37 code), you'll get to a deeper point where you'll see even more `(rember)`s appear in *the **Stack** area*. Your current execution point appears top-most on the ***Stack***; the earliest – bottom-most.

[image]

Notice the ***Variables*** area shows the variables' values for that specific invocation frame.

If you move your mouse cursor and hover over a lower `(rember)` and click on it, you'll see *its* variables' values:

[image]

Racket's debugger gets a bit getting used to.

Also do notice the "last evaluated value" field in **the top left corner** shown in **very small letters** (in the previous image). This is a very important and useful piece of information, while debugging. It *could* use being a *little* bit more visible on the screen.

The reason you don't see the stack of `(rember)`s grow with the first code (p.34),

[image]

is that it is [***tail recursive***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). There is nothing to be done with the result of the deep nested invocation of `rember` except to return it further back; so there's no need to save any state for that. This means the *invocation frame* for `rember` gets reused, replaced, and that's why you only ever see one of them, at the bottom of *the Stack*.

But with the p.37's code there's more stuff to be done with the returned value - a preceding list element must be `cons`ed onto the result. This means that list element must be preserved, remembered somewhere. That somewhere is `rember`'s invocation frame where that list element was accessed as `(car lat)`, for *that* value of `lat`, at *that* point in execution timeline.

Similarly, for all the other functions that have `(else (function (cdr ...` pattern, this means they are *tail-recursive* too. But if you see something like `(else (cons ... (function (cdr ...`, then they are *not*. The `cons` is in the way.

---

To better see what's going  on, we rewrite it in an equational pattern-matching pseudocode:

```erlang
(rember34 a lat) =
    { (null? lat)        ->  '() 
    ; (eq? a (car lat))  ->  (cdr lat)
    ; else               ->  (rember a (cdr lat))
    }
```

This further simplifies to three clauses,

```erlang
rember34 a []          =  []
rember34 a [a, ...as]  =  as
rember34 a [b, ...as]  =  rember a as
```

Is this pseudocode understandable enough just visually, without being explicitly explained? I hope that it is. The other definition is

```erlang
rember37 a []          =  [] 
rember37 a [a, ...as]  =  as
rember37 a [b, ...as]  =  [b, ...rember a as]
```

Now just by looking at these definitions we can see the difference, and what each one does.

The first, `rember34`, goes along the list (which is its second argument), <sup>*`(3rd clause)`*</sup> until it finds `a` in it (its first argument), and if it does <sup>*`(2nd clause)`*</sup>, it returns the rest of the list *at that point*. If there was no `a` found  <sup>*`(3rd clause)`*</sup> and we've reached the end of the list <sup>*`(1st clause)`*</sup> so that the list to continue along is now empty (`[]`), the empty list `[]` is returned <sup>*`(1st clause)`*</sup>.

Makes sense. For example,

```erlang
rember34 3 [1,2,3,4,5]              %   Tail-Recursive Call:
 = rember34 3 [2,3,4,5]             %    Just Returning The Result...
 = rember34 3 [3,4,5]               %     Call Frame Is Reused.
 = [4,5]

rember34 3 [1,2] 
 = rember34 3 [2]
 = rember34 3 []
 = []
```

The second, `rember37`, does the same but with one crucial difference: it keeps each non-matching element before the one that it finds and removes (as before). This means that if there was no such element found, the same list will be recreated. For example,

```erlang
rember37 3 [1,2,3,4,5] 
 = [1, ...rember37 3 [2,3,4,5]]              % the->
       => [2, ...rember37 3 [3,4,5]]         %     stack->
              <= [4,5]                       %           grows
       <= [2,4,5]                            %      <-and
 = [1,2,4,5]                                 %  <-contracts

rember37 3 [1,2] 
 = [1, ...rember37 3 [2]]                    % must remember 1,
       => [2, ...rember37 3 []]              %     and 2, to be used
              <= []                          %          after the recursive call
       <= [2]                                %      has returned its result
 = [1,2]                                     %  to its caller
```

Hopefully this clarifies things.

---

a sidenote: under the tail-recursion [*modulo `cons`*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) optimization, it'd be

```erlang
rember37 3 [1,2,3,4,5] 
 = [1, ...rember37 3 [2,3,4,5]]
 = [1, ...[2, ...rember37 3 [3,4,5]]]
 = [1,2, ...rember37 3 [3,4,5]]
 = [1,2, ...[4,5]]
 = [1,2,4,5]

rember37 3 [1,2] 
 = [1, ...rember37 3 [2]]
 = [1, ...[2, ...rember37 3 []]]
 = [1,2, ...rember37 3 []]
 = [1,2, ...[]]
 = [1,2]
```

which is much like it'd be under lazy evaluation as well!

Comment: Thx! Got own interpretation for p37 now. Please let me if I'm correct.

Apart from calling of rember variables, there are 2 set of processes - “Before else” and “else”

The “else” part can only be executed after “before else" part getting the result. This part is not involved in calling variables

2nd call of variables part is the same on both p34 and p37 examples and only passing the value of “before else” process.

The only difference between 2 examples is the else part process of p34 is just the 2nd call of variables. While there is an independent process on else part of p37 example

Comment: there is only one process. Normally, when we've reached `(cons (car lat) (rember a (cdr lat)))`, we need to evaluate the `(cons A B)` form. the value of `A` is simple to find. to find the value of `B`, we find the value `C` = `(cdr lat)` (also simple to find), go to the side and find the value of `B` = `(rember C)` *according to the same rules*. now that we have `B` calculated, we continue with our `R` = `(cons A B)` task. now that we have both `A` and `B`, it is also easy to calculate `R`.

Comment: I understand what u said and great thx. What I meant was the flow of the data point of view. Value of lat was only looping between null? > Eq? > Cdr lat(rember). The 2nd process (cons...) Is conditional and will only be executed after the first process (if eq? = #t) getting the result other than null. TLS is my first step learning programming. It's really a challenge but I know I'm making progress page by page! Thx again

Comment: ah, ok. not "looping" then, "switching" between the two clauses of the `cond`; "going through" even. that's how `cond` works, the process goes through its clauses one after another sequentially, until the one whose condition returns a *true* value - then, *this* clause is entered. It so happens that it contains a recursive call, which causes our process to again go through the both clauses trying out their conditions *again* - but on a new, *deeper* level of recursion. you're welcome, and happy trails!

Comment: not "looping" then, "switching" as you can see, quite often a beginner like me can't even ask the question properly. The standard code of (atom?) is (and (not (pair? atom)) (not (null? atom))). Instead of true or false. Is that possible to rewrite this function and give result '(not atom but a list) OR '(not atom but an empty list) OR '(this is an atom)?

Comment: anything you can say in English, you can put in Scheme code. try it; if you get problems you can always post a new question, with the code and its (wrong?) output / error messages. :)

Comment: Understand. I will do so but may be it's a better idea to capture my question for now and complete TLS first XD

Answer (score 2):

Let me *strongly* suggest that you use the stepper here, and not the debugger. I think you'll see a more consistent set of reduction rules. Specifically, I don't think you'll see anything "identified as unknown."

To use the stepper: Open a fresh buffer, make sure the language level is set to beginning student with list abbreviations, and paste the definition and the call into the definitions window. Click on "step". I think you'll see the difference between the two evaluations pretty quickly.

Please ask followup questions if anything doesn't make sense!

Comment: the OP misinterpreted the Stack display. the difference was due to tail / non-tail recursion. (I've updated my answer, even with pictures and a haiku about TR.... nobody will see it at this point; oh well).

Comment: I tried both beginning and intermediate and both great. However, seems some primitives are missing on those learning versions of Racket. At least I noticed (pair? ) Is not defined OOTB. So I use (list? ) for defining (atom? )

Comment: You should be able to use "cons?" in place of "pair?". Are there others?

Comment: Racket docs should have the list. I saw that earlier. I didn't know there cons? Will try tonight! Thx